# How to fix shadow terminator artifacts?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, light

I am having issues with my scene. I created a sand dune sort of mesh and everything is all good. I add in an HDRI and then get this:

[image]

As you can see, the sand has some sort of weird shading issue which I believe is called "shadow terminator artifacts". I've only seen three solutions:

1. Up the mesh density (didnt' work, even with my high poly 1mil mesh i got these artifacts)
2. use the shadow terminator removal tool in blender 2.9 (Also didn't work, the shadows became too large)
3. Disable smooth shading. (Did absolutely nothing)

I honestly am confused and have no idea how to fix this. The scene is literally just an HDRI rotated around slightly.

One thing i will note, is that the shading issue goes away when i have a more diffuse HDRI (or none at all)

[image]

And here is everything in the viewport:
[image]

I also have tried switching out the HDRI for something else and still got the artifacts. What else can I try?

EDIT: forgot to mention, I don't get this issue when I render with EEVEE.

Comment: try to change the size of your light, if it's a sun and if you are in Cycles it is called Angle

Comment: @moonboots I'm not using any lamps, just an HDRI.

Comment: so maybe add a light in order to smooth the shadows?

Comment: @moonboots doesn't seem to work really

Comment: could you please pack your images and share your file (only the terrain)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots File size seems to be too large, can't. One thing I do notice is that the issue goes away if i remove the displacement map..

Comment: are you using an image texture for this displacement map? in that case maybe check if it is set to non-color data, olso I think it is supposed to be 32 bit float, and of course the node organisation must be correct

Comment: @moonboots yeah im using this: https://www.textures.com/download/3dscans0014/126018.. Setup is normal i believe and everything in regards to displacement is set to non-color data.

Comment: Oh also I have tried using a different texture and still got issues

Comment: try to share on another platform